# Is it possible to increase the size of the bounding box in an R barplot?

Tags: r

Consider the following `barplot` code.

```
pdf("ThreadCreationLatency.pdf")
B <- c(52.6,26.2,0.6)
pp <- barplot(B, main="Thread Creation to First Instruction", ylab="Time (us)", 
        names.arg=c("std::thread", "Goroutines", "Arachne"),
        cex.names=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, cex.main=1.5, ylim=c(0,60))
text(x=pp , y=B+2, labels=as.character(B), xpd=TRUE, cex=1.5)

dev.off()
```

If I increase `cex.lab` to something like `1.6`, the label size increases, but it overflows the left bounding box of the plot and gets truncated.

Is it possible to increase the size of the bounding box on the left side so that I can have larger labels without getting truncated?

Comment: See `?par` - specifically `par(mar=...)` to adjust the margins on each side

Comment: Give a thorough perusal to this page, I find myself referring back to it a lot: http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/

Answer (score 0):

(This is the base plotting world, so do study the `?par` help page.) It's helpful to remember defaults (or know how to recover them) for `par('mar')`:

```
> par('mar')
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
```

So add 1 to the left side margin which is the second of those numbers:

```
pdf("ThreadCreationLatency.pdf")
B <- c(52.6,26.2,0.6); par(mar=par('mar')+c(0, 1,0,0) )
pp <- barplot(B, main="Thread Creation to First Instruction", ylab="Time (us)", 
        names.arg=c("std::thread", "Goroutines", "Arachne"),
        cex.names=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, cex.main=1.5, ylim=c(0,60))
text(x=pp , y=B+2, labels=as.character(B), xpd=TRUE, cex=1.6)

dev.off()
```